# How do I use the deprecated getFragmentManager() in API Level 28?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In API level 28, `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated. I have used this `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` is solution for this. But how can I implement that in my code.

**Here my activity class code.**

```
  public class AttendanceActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attendence_common_layout);

    if (findViewById(R.id.attendance_fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.attendance_fragment_container, new FragmentAttendance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    ActivityUtils.startActivity(this);

   }

 }
```

Comment: `AndroidStudio` has nothing to do with that .. So try not to mention it in title and in tags . Its an `IDE` .

Comment: @ADM Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
public class AttendanceActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

use

```
public class AttendanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Then, change the below line

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()....
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()....
```

Make sure FragmentAttendance is declared like this:

```
public class FragmentAttendance extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```